# Generate some "random" start times for scripts to run based on a period of time in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, random, random-seed

I'm trying to generate some random seeded times to tell my script when to fire each of the scripts from within a main script.

I want to set a time frame of:

```
START_TIME = "02:00"
END_TIME = "03:00"
```

When it reaches the start time, it needs to look at how many scripts we have to run:

```
script1.do_proc()
script2.alter()
script3.noneex()
```

In this case there are 3 to run, so it needs to generate 3 randomized times to start those scripts with a **minimum** separation of 5 mins between each script but the times must be within the time set in `START_TIME` and `END_TIME`

But, it also needs to know that `script1.main` is ALWAYS the first script to fire, other scripts can be shuffled around (random)

So we could potentially have `script1` running at 01:43 and then `script3` running at 01:55 and then `script2` might run at 02:59

We could also potentially have `script1` running at 01:35 and then `script3` running at 01:45 and then `script2` might run at 01:45 which is also fine.

My script so far can be found below:

```
import random
import pytz
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

import script1
import script2
import script3

START_TIME = "01:21"
END_TIME = "03:00"

while 1:
    try:

        # Set current time & dates for GMT, London
        CURRENT_GMTTIME = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).strftime("%H%M")
        CURRENT_GMTDAY = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/London')).strftime("%d%m%Y")
        sleep(5)

        # Grab old day for comparisons
        try:
            with open("DATECHECK.txt", 'rb') as DATECHECK:
                OLD_DAY = DATECHECK.read()
        except IOError:
             with open("DATECHECK.txt", 'wb') as DATECHECK:
                DATECHECK.write("0")
                OLD_DAY = 0

        # Check for new day, if it's a new day do more
        if int(CURRENT_GMTDAY) != int(OLD_DAY):
            print "New Day"

            # Check that we are in the correct period of time to start running
            if int(CURRENT_GMTTIME) <= int(START_TIME.replace(":", "")) and int(CURRENT_GMTTIME) >= int(END_TIME.replace(":", "")):
                print "Correct time, starting"

                # Unsure how to seed the start times for the scripts below

                script1.do_proc()
                script2.alter()
                script3.noneex()

                # Unsure how to seed the start times for above

                # Save the current day to prevent it from running again today.
                with open("DATECHECK.txt", 'wb') as DATECHECK:
                    DATECHECK.write(CURRENT_GMTDAY)

                print "Completed"

            else:
                pass
        else:
            pass

    except Exception:
        print "Error..."
        sleep(60)
```

## EDIT 31/03/2016

Let's say I add the following

```
SCRIPTS = ["script1.test()", "script2.test()", "script3.test()"]
MAIN_SCRIPT = "script1.test()"
TIME_DIFFERENCE = datetime.strptime(END_TIME, "%H:%M") - datetime.strptime(START_TIME, "%H:%M")
TIME_DIFFERENCE = TIME_DIFFERENCE.seconds
```

- We now have the the number of scripts to run
- We have the list of the script to run.
- We have the name of the main script, the one to run first.
- We have the time in seconds to show how much time we have in total to run all the scripts within.

Surely there is a way we can just plug some sort of loop to make it do it all..

- `for i in range(len(SCRIPTS))`, which is 3 times
- Generate 3 seeds, making sure the minimum time is of `300` and all together the 3 seeds must not exceed `TIME_DIFFERENCE`
- Create the start time based on `RUN_TIME = START_TIME` and then `RUN_TIME = RUN_TIME + SEED[i]`
- First loop would check that that `MAIN_SCRIPT` exists within `SCRIPTS`, if it does then it would run that script first, delete itself from `SCRIPTS` and then on next loops, as it doesn't exist in `SCRIPTS` it would switch to randomly calling one of the other scripts.

## Seeding the times

The following appears to work, there might be an easier way of doing this though.

```
CALCULATE_SEEDS = 0
NEW_SEED = 0
SEEDS_SUCESSS = False
SEEDS = []

while SEEDS_SUCESSS == False:
    # Generate a new seed number
    NEW_SEED = random.randrange(0, TIME_DIFFERENCE)

    # Make sure the seed is above the minimum number
    if NEW_SEED > 300:
        SEEDS.append(NEW_SEED)

    # Make sure we have the same amount of seeds as scripts before continuing.
    if len(SEEDS) == len(SCRIPTS):

        # Calculate all of the seeds together
        for SEED in SEEDS:
            CALCULATE_SEEDS += SEED
        # Make sure the calculated seeds added together is smaller than the total time difference
        if CALCULATE_SEEDS >= TIME_DIFFERENCE:
            # Reset and try again if it's not below the number
            SEEDS = []
        else:
            # Exit while loop if we have a correct amount of seeds with minimum times.
            SEEDS_SUCESSS = True
```

Comment: is the number of scripts changing, I mean it's not 3 or 4, but can be more ?

Comment: @minhhn2910 yes, it does. Is there a way I can put functions into an array to work out how many seeds I need & to shuffle the scripts (except script1)

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: My last question (sry for a lot of questions because it's not clear enough): Between ``START_TIME`` and ``END_TIME`` do you need to run all scripts or some of them?. I think it's pretty hard to generate the random timing like you want that can accommodate all of the scripts. (Because maximum interval is not set while the minimum is 5 mins)

Comment: @minhhn2910 All the scripts need to run but only once each all within the time between `START_TIME` and `END TIME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta` to compute time differences.  This code assumes all three processes run on the same day

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from random import randint

YR, MO, DY = 2016, 3, 30
START_TIME = datetime( YR, MO, DY, 1, 21, 00 )   # "01:21"
END_TIME = datetime( YR, MO, DY, 3, 0, 0 )       # "3:00"
duration_all = (END_TIME - START_TIME).seconds
d1 = ( duration_all - 600 ) // 3          
#       
rnd1 = randint(0,d1)
rnd2 = rnd1 + 300 + randint(0,d1)
rnd3 = rnd2 + 300 + randint(0,d1)
#      
time1 = START_TIME + timedelta(seconds=rnd1)
time2 = START_TIME + timedelta(seconds=rnd2)
time3 = START_TIME + timedelta(seconds=rnd3)
#
print (time1)
print (time2)
print (time3)
```

Values of `rnd1`, `rnd2`and `rnd3` are at least 5 minutes (300 seconds) apart.

Values of `rnd3` cannot be greater than the total time interval (`3 * d1 + 600`).  So all three times occur inside the interval.

NB You did not specify how much time each script runs.  That is why I did not use `time.sleep`.  A possible option would be `threading.Timer` (see python documentation).

Comment: Each script just runs once per day, It's somewhat confusing code that you posted. I can't actually work out how it works even with your explanation.

Comment: That makes much more sense, significantly easier to read too.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you store all the method.func() in an array and, as u described, subsequent scripts must be at least 5 mins after script1. They can be executed randomly, so we can launch multiple processes and let them sleep for a period before they can automatically start. (Timing is in seconds)

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import os
import random
import time
#store all scripts you want to execute here
eval_scripts = ["script1.test()","script2.test()", "script3.test()"]

#run job on different processes. non-blocking
def run_job(eval_string,time_sleep):
    #print out script + time to test
    print eval_string + " " + str(time_sleep)
    time.sleep(time_sleep) #wait to be executed
    #time to start
    eval(eval_string)


def do_my_jobs():
    start_time = []
    #assume the duration between start_time and end_time is 60 mins, leave some time for other jobs after the first job (5-10 mins). This is just to be careful in case random.randrange returns the largest number
    #adjust this according to the duration between start_time and end_time since calculating (end_time - star_time) is trivial.
    proc1_start_time = random.randrange(60*60 - 10*60)
    start_time.append(proc1_start_time)
    #randomize timing for other procs != first script
    for i in range(len(eval_scripts)-1):
            #randomize time from (proc1_start_time + 5 mins) to (end_time - star_time)
            start_time.append(random.randint(proc1_start_time+5*60, 60*60))

    for i in range(len(eval_scripts)):
            p_t = Process(target = run_job, args = (eval_scripts[i],start_time[i],))
            p_t.start()
            p_t.join()
```

Now all you need to do is to call do_my_jobs() only ONCE at START_TIME every day.

Comment: While that works, it's not exactly what I am looking for.. I've edited the main post maybe you have a suggestion regarding my edit. I am pretty sure it can be done just can't figure it out correctly.

Comment: So now your question is "how to run MAIN_SCRIPT first and iterate over a permutation of other scripts" or "is there any better seed methods ?".
Another thing is 5 mins is the minimum interval between scripts, but how long will your scripts run ? I don't know how long so I suggested using multiprocess. It will ensure the minimum time interval between firing each script.